# How to save the returned data from a Flexcard Action

Tags: error-messages, omnistudio, integration-procedure

I want to save the response from an Integration Procedure that is triggered from a button on a Flexcard to the Flexcard's JSON:

[image]

- The one button will throw an error (not passing a `recordId` to the IP)
- The other button will successfully update the Opportunity record

The response from the IP for a successful update is:

```json
{
  "result": {
    "error": false,
    "errorMessage": null
  },
  "success": true
}
```

and when it throws an error:

```json
{
  "result": {
    "error": true,
    "errorMessage": "Required fields are missing: [Name, StageName, CloseDate]"
  },
  "success": false
}
```

It seems like the response is not saved to the JSON of the Flexcard. I followed the instructions as per the Salesforce help file [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.os_call_a_data_source_from_an_action_on_a_flexcard.htm&type=5).

When I click the button, the **Action Debugger** shows that the IP ran and it returned the expected response:

[image]

When looking at the **Data JSON** tab, the response is not included in the `cards` JSON node (as shown in the Salesforce [help](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.os_call_a_data_source_from_an_action_on_a_flexcard.htm&type=5) file):

[image]

On both buttons, the option `IgnoreResponse = FALSE`, but try as I might the IP's response is not added to the JSON.

Any assistance/suggestions/lessons learnt would be appreciated

Thanks!